# Devise: Associate record on login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I added a custom devise sessions controller to associate records after someone logged in:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    before_create :associate_calculation

    def associate_calculation
        Calculation.find(self.calculation_id).user_id = self.id
        Calculation.last.save!
    end

end
```

Here are the request parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JOQQcCTB9tkVegDgHP/ww8hu5qSzNWlu+4HZZ9AmQGYVO60f3BliwEYT+HKAGPsOOqbipSgj/xSqcDLqueOPZw==", "user"=>{"calculation_id"=>"48759708645478633", "email"=>"jonas@slooob.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Signin"}
```

I also added `attr_accessor :calculation_id` to the `User` model.

Still, the corresponding calculation does not get associated to the signed in user.

I also tried to manually attach a calculation to a user:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    before_create :associate_calculation

    def associate_calculation
        Calculation.last.user_id = User.first.id
        Calculation.last.save!
    end

end
```

That did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

```
def associate_calculation
    c = Calculation.find(self.calculation_id)
    c.user_id = self.id #self.id is probably also wrong. maybe current_user?  
    #Calculation.save! You can not save a class. You need to save an instance
    c.save
end
```

Save the object not the class. You should have had an error so also make sure the method is actually being called by adding a trace to your log file and check the output.

I also suspect that self.id may not be what you are looking for either. Perhaps you should be looking for current_user.id? or whatever the name of the currently logged in user object is at this point. Also if you prefer using the model relationships then maybe something like

```
c.user = current_user
c.save
```

The above all assumes that you have the correct associations e.g. user has_many calculations and calculation belongs_to user and that your database reflects this. I say this because you mentioned:

> I also added attr_accessor :calculation_id to the User model.

Which is clearly wrong and would never give you the desired results so it looks like you have a little confusion

just adding a method to your model would not have any effect at all. Even if it did work your solution would only ever allow one calculation for a user yet your code implies you would have many calculations.
This leads me on to think that you should not just be finding a calculation but should be creating one?

Did you set your routes properly? For the extended controller to take effect you would need somethign like

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def destroy
    reset_session
    super
  end
end

# In your routes

devise_for :users do
  get "/users/sign_out", :to => "sessions#destroy", :as => "destroy_user_session"
end
```

Comment: The problem seems to bee that `associate_calculation` does not get called in the first place.

Comment: @jonhue that would explain why you were not seeing the errors in your code. So when you get that sorted, different question? then using the above you should get your desired result

Comment: @jonhue I have updated my answer considerably. Hope it helps you to get to the solution you actually need

Comment: I only added `attr_accessor` to the user because it allows me to add a calculation_id (from params) to the singin form. My goal is to set the `user_id` column of the calculation accordingly. Associations (has_many/belongs_to) are set up as you anticipated.

Comment: @jonhue that's good that you have the associations correctly setup. My confusion was over the attr_accessor. Perhaps a better solution would be to setup a global variable `@calculation` to represent the calculation object you need in the controller's action that could then be accessed when you need it rather than adding an attr_accessor? This would be the normal approach

Comment: That approach makes it complicated to create a simple form and introduces a lot of additional logic. Nevertheless, the "real" problem lies in the extended SessionsController, since the `associate_calculation` method does not get called

Comment: @jonhue I've updated my answer that might help with the session controller method not getting called. Not sure why you would think my suggested approach complicates anything. It's really simple but maybe I haven't communicated properly. Sorry. Anyway hope it helps. good luck!